# Serving multiple items in the same API call in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API in Rails 3, and I got the following problem. The user got several "resources" like phone, email, address, website and occupation.

I would like to build a resource in the API that get all the users "items" in the same call. Is this possible? How can this be done?

```
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @phones = @user.phones.where(:privacy => nil)
    @emails = @user.emails.where(:privacy => nil)
    @websites = @user.websites.where(:privacy => nil)
    @addresses = @user.addresses.where(:privacy => nil)
    @occupations = @user.occupations.where(:privacy => nil)

    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { render :text => 'Use either JSON or XML' }
        format.json { render :json => {@phones,@emails}, :only => [:firstname, :lastname, :nickname, :email, :bio] }
        format.xml { render :xml => @phones, :only => [:firstname, :lastname, :nickname, :email, :bio] }

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to have a separate model(object) (with out active record) to hold those data as a single class.

Ex:

```
class APIUser

   attr_accessor : name, phone, web_site etc..

end
```

then I will feed all the data to the above user model and expose it as a service. As I can see, that way you have more control over the details. What i mean by that is, for the API you can have a separate layer of objects and expose them through controllers.

By that way when ever you want to change API data, you only need to worry about your API object. and same thing apply for the OR models

cheers

sameera

Comment: Ok, sounds interesting, I will look into this. But isn´t this possible the way I try to do it? How can my code be modified to serve all results in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

You better build your own json or xml as output.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml # index.xml.builder
    format.json render :partial => "show.json"
end
```